# Change field names with names from a dataframe

Tags: r

Using the iris dataset:

```
iris1<-head(iris)
```

I want to change the column headers so that they match the lookup df below, so that for example Sepal.Length changes to SepLen and so on.

I want to do this using the lookup df below rather than changing each one at a time.

```
iriscols<-c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",  "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width",  "Species" )
newcols<-c("SepLen","SepWid","PetLen","PetWid","Spec")
lookup<-data.frame(iriscols,newcols, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Can anyone suggest an approach to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
iris1 <- iris1 %>% 
   rename_with(~newcols, all_of(iriscols))
names(iris1)
#[1] "SepLen" "SepWid" "PetLen" "PetWid" "Spec"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a named vector instead of a data frame. This strategy can be very useful in other settings as well.

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  rename(setNames(iriscols, newcols))
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a named vector built from your lookup table as a look up vector to recode names.

```
names(iris) <- setNames(lookup$newcols,lookup$iriscols)[names(iris)]
```